# What's with the 1366x768 resolution for laptops/notebooks?

Tags: laptop, resolution

I've been looking to replace my current laptop 14" (1440x900 resolution) with a new one.

But it seems most new 14" laptops are stuck to 1366x768 resolutions max???

What happened to the higher resolutions?

Comment: What do you mean *What happened to them*?

Comment: I mean, laptop makers don't make higher resolution anymore?

Comment: Yes, they do. But the panels are usually larger in size and/or more expensive.

Comment: At 1440x900, the [aspect ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratios) is 16:10, while 1366x768 has a ratio of 16:9, which is the *much more common* widescreen associated TVs, movies, etc. As such, a 16:9 widescreen video fits nicely into 1366x768 without needing a letterbox like it does for 1440x900. Laptops use LCD/LED screens which only look good at their native resolution, so using a higher resolution would require a better, more expensive screen; 1366x768 is the next best, cheapest thing. You can still use higher resolutions by connecting an external monitor to the VGA/HDMI port.

Answer (score 10):

It's the [*standard* HD ready resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_resolutions). I assume that's why manufacturers like it.

But it's not like no higher resolutions are available. For example, the latest MacBook Pro can provide [2880x1800 resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macbook_pro#Third_generation:_Retina). But I would assume that costs a few bucks more than the laptop you were looking at.

Answer (score 3):

It really comes down to cost a 1366x768 display is cheaper than one with more pixels, less pixels = less cost, and thats the bottom  line for <del>most</del> all PC manufactures. Unfortunately the market does not demand nor supply a great choice of 14" laptops with higher screen resolutions, since they are not everywhere. You average PC buyer is unfortuatly thinking *"Why would I want a $600-800 laptop with a high res screen when I can get a 15" laptop with a 1366x768 screen for $499."* If your looking for higher than 1366 x 768, it going to be an optional build to order item at best that you are going to have to select and search for from optional features available on various notebooks.

Higher resolution displays are generally reserved as add ons to more premium laptops. Eg in the Dell case, only their higher end business laptops such as the Lattitude series even offer better than 1366 x 768 in a 13" /14"  form factor. The [Dell Latitude E5420](http://www.dell.com/us/soho/p/latitude-e5420/pd?oc=slct541att&model_id=latitude-e5420) was the only Dell laptop to offer a higher resolution option of 1600 x 900 for $50 more.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you need to make sure you have a decent seperate graphics card to handle higher resolutions properly. So either get a slightly more expensive laptop and then you'll have your beloved higher resolutions or deal with the lower resolution on cheaper models.

Comment: Yeah, but I was assuming the new Ivy Bridge could handle any resolution up to 1080p :P

Comment: The (now old) Sandy Bridge can easily handle *extending* the desktop onto a 1920 x 1080 screen. In fact, I'm pretty sure the previous Intel integrated graphics could handle it, and I assume the AMD ones could too. Of course, larger resolutions, especially larger default resolutions, could result in increased resource usage and slowdowns.