# Which aspect ratio to choose for 1366x768 resolution to play game at monitor physical aspect ratio?

Tags: display, resolution, gaming, aspect-ratio

I want to use aspect ratio as close as possible to monitor physical aspect ratio. My monitor physical resolution is 1366x768. Which aspect ratio to choose?

Comment: @grawity Overwatch. It offers to choose from 16:9 or 16:10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aspect ratio is literally the ratio of width to height (assuming the pixels themselves are square), so just divide the numbers and compare for yourself.

The aspect ratio of 1366x768 is 1366:768, which is *almost* 16:9, although more precisely 16:8.9956076..., which is just a *tiny* bit away.

In general, 1366x768 is a strange resolution, causing problems with EDID, etc. There are posts about it specifically, e.g. [Why does 1366x768 resolution exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/946086/why-does-1366x768-resolution-exist)